# Linqpad - Linq to Sql Ambiguous table and linked server name

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linqpad

Using Linqpad & Linq to Sql, I am trying to join some data from a table in the database to data that which is contained on a linked server.

I have followed the instructions to create a connection with the linked server (http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx#cross-database)

My problem seems to be that I have the table in the database, let's say it is called "MyData", and the database in the linked server both with the same name ("MyData".

When I try to reference "MyData" in a query I am shown an error

> CS0229 Ambiguity between 'TypedDataContext.MyData' and 'TypedDataContext.MyData'

I know I am setting up the connection to the linked server correctly because I can create a connection to a different database on the linked server, one that does not have a naming conflict, and am able to successfully query from that linked database.

Is there a way that i can specify accurately the table or the linked server database, or have Linqpad generate unique names for the two items in question?

Comment: EF cannot be two or more same table names.

Comment: Don't see that issue here. If I have a linked table from a database called Demo, then normally the table in that server will be referenced either as `Demo.MyData` or `DemoTypes.MyData`

Comment: Hi, @sgmoore, in your scenario, if you reference the table "MyData" in the linked server database using "Demo.MyData", how would you reference a table called "Demo" that existed in the local database connection (i.e. not via the linked server)?

Comment: If I have a table called Demo in my local database, then when I add the Demo database, the names used for the the linked database become `DemoDb` and `DemoDbTypes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to work around my problem. I happened to delete the connection, and when i was recreating the db connection in linqpad, I noticed there were options that allowed me to tweak the names of the generated objects.

[image]

I was able to change the settings such that the database on the linked server had a pluralized name, while the local table was singular.

With this in place there was no longer ambiguity between the two names.